# How to make that during testing H2 does not insert data into the table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, h2

I use Spring Boot with H2 in-memory database with schema.sql and data.sql files that create the schema and fill it with data, respectively.

Everything works fine, but when I want to test sql queries and add the required records to the database myself, I run into the problem that both my record from the test and the others from data.sql are added to the database.

Is it possible to disable adding data from data.sql for the duration of the test?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an emtpy `data.sql` file in `src/test/resources`

This will overwrite the `data.sql` file from `src/main/resources`

Comment: Unfortunately, I get `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script from resource [URL [file:/C:/Java/IdeaProjects/university-manager-spring-boot/target/test-classes/data.sql]]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'script' must not be null or empty`

Comment: Then you can add any statement like this "select * from dual;"

Answer (score 0):

Working for me: create in `src/test/resources` file `application.properties` with parameter `spring.sql.init.data-locations=testdata.sql`. Then create `testdata.sql` with statement `select * from dual;`